# How to make Referral System Website in MERN Stack?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

I want to build a web app in which if a user share a link and someone who use that link will redirect to main website where he/she can buy Movie, Games, etc. and if he/she will buy any thing on website then the user who shares that link will get some points.

Like in campus ambassador programs, campus ambassador will get some points for referring any thing.

So how I can implement this using MERN stack ?

Comment: First you want to build the Database, then the ExpressJS middleware, then the ReactJS front-end, then run it on NodeJS. Then you're done!

But seriously, how would you like help? Are you asking people how to write all of the code for this project? Are you asking for design help? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: I am asking for just design.     How will we keep track that someone is buying anything with referral link and how to add specific points to that invitor?

Answer (score 0):

In your API, you will want multiple endpoints:

1. Endpoint that signs up a user. This will build a `User` with a `username`, `password`, `points`, `referral code`, and a `list of referred users` in the database.
2. Endpoint that signs up a user with a referral code. This will build the same thing as the first endpoint with an added `referred by` value in the database.

If the second endpoint is used, you can add the newly signed up user's data to the `list of referred users` of the referrer.

When the newly added user buys something, you can add to the `points` total of the referrer.

---

In my opinion, this does not seem like a job suited best for MongoDB. A relational database would probably make this a lot more straightforward.